# All data is lost when using sf::st_cast

Tags: r, r-sf

In the code below I first create a rectangle from two horizontal lines and two vertical lines. Then I use `st_polygonize` to create a polygon. Finally, I use `st_cast` to create an object of class,

> [1] "XY"      "POLYGON" "sfg"

which is what I require. However, when I try to do something similar with a wave it fails. I create the wave polygon by duplicating a wave line, moving it up, and adding sides.

`wave_gc` plots OK but when I execute:

`wave_poly <- class(st_cast(wave_gc, "POLYGON"))`

wave_poly is empty. Why is this? How do I end up with an object of class

> [1] "XY"      "POLYGON" "sfg"

that works?

---

```
library(sf)
library(transformr)

# Rectangle #########################
# two vertical lines
v_lines <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(0,0),c(0,1)), rbind(c(3,0),c(3,1))))

# two horizontal lines
h_lines <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(0,0),c(3,0)), rbind(c(0,1),c(3,1))))
all_lines <- c(v_lines, h_lines)

rect_gc  <-  st_polygonize(all_lines)
rect_poly <- st_cast(rect_gc, "POLYGON")

class(rect_gc)
# [1] "XY"                 "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION" "sfg"  
class(rect_poly)
# [1] "XY"      "POLYGON" "sfg"
rect_poly

#################################################################
# Wave
################################################################

w1 <- path_waves(st = TRUE)[[1]]
w2 <- w1 

# Add to second column, y values
w2[,2] <- w2[,2] + 0.1

# Vertical bars
nr <- nrow(w1)
v_bars <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(w1[1, 1], w1[1, 2]), c(w2[1, 1], w2[1, 2])), 
                                  rbind(c(w1[nr, 1], w1[nr, 2]), c(w2[nr, 1], w2[nr, 2]))))
two_waves <- st_multilinestring(list(w1, w2))
full_wave <- c(v_bars, two_waves)

wave_gc = st_polygonize(full_wave)
wave_poly <- class(st_cast(wave_gc, "POLYGON"))

class(wave_gc)
# [1] "XY"                 "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION" "sfg"   

plot(wave_gc)

wave_poly
# [1] "XY"      "POLYGON" "sfg"
```

Comment: You've written `wave_poly <- class(st_cast(wave_gc, "POLYGON"))` which returns the class of the cast object. The actual cast object itself looks fine.

Comment: You are correct. Thank-you.